# Trouble setting custom view in my ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have a list view with various element and that updates quite many times.
I wanted to add a single seprator line after some random positions, like, after 3rd element, 7th element, 17th element, 19element etc.

so I desgined an xml file containing a seperator and inflate it on those position using custom `SimpleAdapter`. However, when I run my code , the seperator is added on weird positions and make my list looks too ugly and sometimmes gives `Unfortunately, yourApp has stopped` error

I have never worked with custom adapter before and have no idea what am I doing wrong.

This is my simple code and I have added comments for explanation,

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> newsList, int resource,String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, newsList, resource, from, to);

        this.context = context;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // TestApp.endPos holds the positions (it keep changing) after which i want to add                
        // separator
        if (position == TestApp.endPos){
            /* my Arraylist is of type HashMap<String, Object>
             * I have added an empty element and add the seperator view in                  
             * it.
             */
            TestApp.arrayList.add(new HashMap<String, Object>());
            // heads is an xml file of my separator
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.heads, null);
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me how can I simplify my problem and what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super.getView` inflates as many views as can be visible at a single time. Later it will just re-use them.

Since you later inflate your own layout, it is cached on top. In the end `super.getView` starts returning your custom views in random positions.

To overcome this you need to tell the adapter that there are 2 types of views so it caches them both separately.

Here are sample methods (not tested but should work):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (position == TestApp.endPos) {
        // Handle separator views manually
        TestApp.arrayList.add(new HashMap<String, Object>());

        // If separator is not yet cached, create the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.heads, null);
        }
    } else {
        // Normal views are handled by the adapter
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // There are 2 types: separator and normal
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == TestApp.endPos) {
        // Separator view
        return 0;
    } else {
        // Normal view
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note: having 2 types, means that 2 types of views will be cached and re-used.

Comment: A much better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `getView` method you should determine whether you want the view with the `seperator` or not then inflate that view for the item:

```
if (view == null) {
      if (showSeperatorItem)
          view = _activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item__row_layout_with_seperator, parent, false);
      else
          view = _activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item__row_layout, parent, false);
}
```

Comment: Could still fail, unless you inflate everytime `getView` is called, which would be very inefficient.

Comment: @user3249477 Agreed, I wasn't aware of `getItemViewType` posted in your answer above. Everyday's a school day.